# How to exchange values inside a dict (based on Function Arguments)

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Assuming the following dictionary in Python:

```
original_dict = {'place_01': 'Tom',
                 'place_02': 'John',
                 'place_03': 'Steve',
                 'place_04': 'Mark'}
```

I would like to define a function that allows me to exchange a defined pair values list.
My function should look like:

```
def change_position(mydict, change_from, change_to):
```

Passing the following arguments:

```
new_dict = change_position(original_dict, ['Tom','John'], ['Mark','Steve'])
```

Desidered result should be:

```
new_dict = {'place_01': 'Mark',
            'place_02': 'Steve',
            'place_03': 'John',
            'place_04': 'Tom'}
```

basically:

- 'Tom' has been exchanged with 'Mark'
- 'John' has been exchanged Steve)

Comment: Where is your code to get there? [mre]? Where is the problem? Do you knwo the dict.items() method that lets you iterate the whole dict and that you can use to do this exchange?

Comment: Iterating over the dictionaries key/value pairs with a view to modifying values is fraught with danger because although keys are unique, values are not. Therefore if you want to substitute the value 'John' with 'Mark' then how would you know which 'John' you're changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
def change_position(mydict, c1, c2):
   d = {**dict(zip(c1, c2)), **dict(zip(c2, c1))}
   return {a:d[b] for a, b in mydict.items()}

original_dict = {'place_01': 'Tom', 'place_02': 'John', 'place_03': 'Steve', 'place_04': 'Mark'}
result = change_position(original_dict, ['Tom', 'John'], ['Mark', 'Steve'])
```

Output:

```
{'place_01': 'Mark', 'place_02': 'Steve', 'place_03': 'John', 'place_04': 'Tom'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Requirement:** values being unique in the dict

---

You need

- a copy of `my_dict` to apply the changes
- a reversed dict `value > key` to know where to apply the changes

Then iterate and swap

```
def change_position(mydict, change_from, change_to):
    result = {**mydict}
    mappings = {v: k for k, v in mydict.items()}
    for val_from, val_to in zip(change_from, change_to):
        key_from, key_to = mappings[val_from], mappings[val_to]
        result[key_to], result[key_from] = mydict[key_from], mydict[key_to]
    return result
```

Gives

```
original_dict = {'place_01': 'Tom', 'place_02': 'John', 'place_03': 'Steve', 'place_04': 'Mark'}
new_dict = change_position(original_dict, ['Tom', 'John'], ['Mark', 'Steve'])
print(new_dict)  # {'place_01': 'Mark', 'place_02': 'Steve', 'place_03': 'John', 'place_04': 'Tom'}
```